# Supersingular elliptic curve over finite field char=2

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

The exercise 5.7 in chapter V of J. Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, is following:

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve with char($K$)=2.
Then E is supersingular if and only if j(E)=0.

I have that E/K is given by two ways :

$E : y^2+xy=x^3+a_2x^2+a_6$, with $j(E)=\frac{1}{a_6}$
or $E : y^2+a_3y=x^3+a_4x+a_6$ with $j(E)=0$.

How to prove that the first is not supersingular? i.e is ordinary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve
$$E : y^2+xy=x^3+a_2x^2+a_6$$
contains the point $P=(0,\sqrt{a_6})$. Of course, this point may live over a quadratic extension of $K$, but that's okay.  You can check using the addition law that
$$ [2]P = \mathcal{O}, $$
and hence $E(\overline K)$ has a non-trivial $2$-torsion point. Therefore $E$ is ordinary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm honored to talk you.